# Creating an offset dynamically with Divs

Tags: php, jquery, html, css

I have a php loop that is adding data dynamically as seen below:

```
<?php $counter = 1; foreach($getFeatured->data as $data){?>
  <div class="col-lg-4">
     <img class="img-rounded" src="iwebimage.axd?qid=<?php echo $data->nomineeQID; ?>">
     <br /><br />
     <p><a href="Person.aspx?accountname=corp\<?php echo $data->nomineeNTID; ?>" target="_BLANK"><?php echo $data->nomineeName; ?></a><br /><small><em><?php echo $data->departmentName; ?></em></small></p>
     <hr class="divider">
     <p><?php echo string_limit_words($data->situation,30); ?></p>
     <br /><a type="button" name="viewSubmission" submissionID="<?php echo $data->submissionID; ?>" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;View Story</a>
  </div>
  <?php $counter++; } ?>
```

There will always be a max of 3 but never less than 1. My issue is that its creating a `col-lg-4` div each time even if there is 1 so its always to the left. I need to create an offset depending on how many are there.

If 1 then `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">`

If 2 then `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-2">` on the first one and `<div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-0">` on the second one

If 3 then `<div class="col-md-4>` no offset needed.

I am over thinking this and not sure if there is an easy way to accomplish it. I am just stuck on the logic.

Comment: you want to check only three times ? or nested ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$data = $getFeatured->data;
$count = count($data);
```

will get you how many you have.

Then

```
switch ($count)
{
   case 1:
       do what you must case it's one
       break;
   case 2:
       do what you must case it's two
   etc etc etc
}
```

Comment: The issue is when it is equal to 2 results. The first one needs the offset, the second does not.